# Consulta SQL en PHP con LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

Buenos días, estoy realizando la siguiente consulta en PHP, no me manda ningún error pero no me arroja nada como resultados.

```
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT Nombre, Campania, Puesto, Turno FROM usuarios
INNER JOIN campania ON usuarios.IdCampania=campania.IdCampania
INNER JOIN puesto ON usuarios.IdPuesto=puesto.IdPuesto
INNER JOIN turno ON usuarios.IdTurno=turno.IdTurno
WHERE Nombre LIKE '%':nombre'%' ");
$sql->execute(array(':nombre'=>$nombre));
$rs = $sql->fetchAll();

<table class="mitabla col-12 col-m-6">
    <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Campaña</th>
        <th>Puesto</th>
        <th>Turno</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($rs as $resultado): ?>  
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $resultado['Nombre'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $resultado['Campania'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $resultado['Puesto'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $resultado['Turno'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme . Gracias.

Comment: Solo para descartar, si haces tu consulta directa en SQL ¿Sí te arroja resultados?

Comment: Si realizo la consulta directa si me arroja resultados, por ejemplo:  SELECT Nombre, Campania, Puesto, Turno FROM usuarios
INNER JOIN campania ON usuarios.IdCampania=campania.IdCampania
INNER JOIN puesto ON usuarios.IdPuesto=puesto.IdPuesto
INNER JOIN turno ON usuarios.IdTurno=turno.IdTurno
WHERE Nombre LIKE '%CE%'

Comment: yo hacia esto: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM individuo WHERE nombre LIKE :term OR apellido LIKE :term OR genero LIKE :term";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $term = $_REQUEST['term'] . '%';
            $stmt->bindParam(':term', $term);
            $stmt->execute();`

Answer (score 2):

Listo, quedo solo añadiendo un espacio adicional entre el placeholder y los signos de porcentaje

```
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT Nombre, Campania, Puesto, Turno FROM usuarios
INNER JOIN campania ON usuarios.IdCampania=campania.IdCampania
INNER JOIN puesto ON usuarios.IdPuesto=puesto.IdPuesto
INNER JOIN turno ON usuarios.IdTurno=turno.IdTurno
WHERE Nombre LIKE '%' :nombre '%' ");
$sql->execute(array(':nombre'=>$nombre));
$rs = $sql->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Deberías marcar tu pregunta como solucionada.

Answer (score 0):

Diría que el problema lo tiene en el `where`. Estás haciendo que busque `'%'nombre'%'` que se traduciría a cualquier nombre que contenga `'CE'` (por ejemplo)

No tienes que poner entre comillas el `%`. Sería `'%:nombre%'`

Comment: De igual manera no me muestra ningún resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Hola podrías probar anteponiendo el nombre de la tabla antes del campo a seleccionar algo así `SELECT usuario.Nombre, compania.Campania...` y asi para las demás